# how to load the default active class with href, while loading the page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, navbar

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked project-body" style="background-color: white">
            <?php foreach($get_policies as $policies) : ?>
                <li role="presentation" class="<?php echo $policies['policies_id'] == $policies_id ? "active" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'policies/index/'.$policies['policies_id'] ?>"><?php echo $policies['policies_title'] ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

i have the above code snippet, where i can display all the policies in vertically. Now i want the first policies should be loaded to the while loading the page. make the class active by default with policies loaded.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, sorry.

Comment: @FlashThunder  i have displayed the policies list in vertical navbar. where i want the first policy would be loaded by default and make active navbar.

Comment: @Rakesh. From the code you have given, one can only tell you how to add the "active" class to it. You will need to add more code where/how the policy loads. Please add full code and then ask your question.

Comment: @Rakesh I mean u want apply dynamically active class or default

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child for doing this

```
$('.project-body li:first-child').addClass('active');
```

Comment: not only make the active and i make the first policy will be loaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to check if li have active class, get href then use window location.href:

```
if($('.project-body li').hasClass('active'))
{
   window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In php way

Assuming your URL is

```
<?php echo base_url().'policies/index/'.$policies['policies_id'] ?>
```

When you click on the `<li>` link, to get the polilcies_id from the URL you can use `$this->uri->segment(n); // n=1 for controller, n=2 for method, etc`

for example
`localhost/policies/index/4` where `4` is the `policies_id`, `this->uri->segment(3)`

```
<li role="presentation" class="<?php echo $policies['policies_id'] == this->uri->segment(3) ? "active" : "" ?>"> YOUR LINK </li>
```